# Making a variable that can access itself

Tags: python, variables

I have a code that goes like this:

```
x = [1, 2, x[0]+x[1]]    #Leads to an error rather than resulting in [1,2,3]
print(x)
```

So my question is, how do you make a **variable** that can access itself?

Comment: You don't. You can define the first two elements and then add the third on another line. It is not possible to refer to `x[0]` because `x` doesn't exist yet

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is not possible to do this. First of all, variables don't **do** anything, so they cannot "access" anything. `x[0]+x[1]` is an **expression**, and its *value is computed*, *before* `x` can be assigned. Since there was not already an `x`, this causes an error. It has nothing to do with the fact that the expression says `x` in it and that it's part of a list that will be assigned to `x`. It has everything to do with the fact that `x` **doesn't exist yet**.

Comment: The question cannot be answered properly because it does not make sense as asked, because it is based on fundamental misconceptions.

Comment: It's really hard to understand when this would ever be needed. Since you are defining a literal, you have the literal values `1`, and `2` at your disposal. You should be able to simply do `x = [1, 2, 1 + 2]`. Do you have a real-world example where this would be useful?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it like that, because `x` isn't defined until that statement finishes executing. Best you can do is something like this:

```
x = [1, 2]
x.append(sum(x))
```

In Python 3.8 and later, you can use the "walrus" assignment operator `:=` to create variables that refer to the individual list items, then add them. This isn't exactly what you want, but it's close:

```
x = [a:=1, b:=2, a+b]
```

This is functionally equivalent to:

```
a, b = 1, 2
x = [a, b, a+b]
```

Which is also perfectly fine, and might express your intent better.